# Error: No string encryptor registered for hibernate with name "hibernateStringEncryptor" in with jasypt

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a problem with Jasyt with Spring Boot and Hibernate.

When i try to write encrypted password into database i got an error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'receptionistController': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException: No string encryptor registered for hibernate with name "hibernateStringEncryptor"
```

hibernateStringEncryptor is registred in Configuration class

```
@Configuration

@EnableTransactionManagement

@ComponentScan(basePackages = "medical.center")

public class HibernateConfig {

@Bean
public void Test(){
 System.out.println("Test");
}

public EnvironmentStringPBEConfig encryptorConfiguration(){

    EnvironmentStringPBEConfig encryptor = new EnvironmentStringPBEConfig();
    encryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    encryptor.setPasswordSysPropertyName("beaver.encryption.password");
    return encryptor;
}

public StandardPBEStringEncryptor standardStringEncryptor(){

    StandardPBEStringEncryptor stringEncryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
    stringEncryptor.setConfig(encryptorConfiguration());
    return stringEncryptor;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernatePBEStringEncryptor hibernateStringEncryptor(){
    HibernatePBEStringEncryptor stringEncryptor = new HibernatePBEStringEncryptor();
    stringEncryptor.setEncryptor(standardStringEncryptor());
    stringEncryptor.setRegisteredName("hibernateStringEncryptor");
    return stringEncryptor;
}
```

**And User Class:**

```
@Entity
@TypeDef(
    name="encryptedString", 
    typeClass=EncryptedStringType.class, 
    parameters={@Parameter(name="encryptorRegisteredName",
                           value="hibernateStringEncryptor")}


public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String login;
@Autowired
@Type(type="encryptedString")
private String password;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
@Column(nullable=true)
private String email;
@Column(nullable=true)
private String phone;
@Column(nullable=true)
private LocalDate bornDate;
@CreatedDate
private LocalDateTime createTime;
@LastModifiedDate
private LocalDateTime modDate;
@Transient
private final static String[] rolesArray = { "Admin", "Doctor", "Patient", "Receptionist" };
private int role;
@Autowired(required=false)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Column(nullable = true)
private List<UserMessage> userMessagesRecive;
@Autowired(required=false)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Column(nullable = true)
private List<UserMessage> userMessagesSend;

public static String[] getRolesArray() {
    return rolesArray;
}

public void setCreateTime(LocalDateTime createTime) {
    this.createTime = createTime;
}

public void setModDate(LocalDateTime modDate) {
    this.modDate = modDate;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstMame) {
    this.firstName = firstMame;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public LocalDate getBornDate() {
    return bornDate;
}

public void setBornDate(LocalDate bornDate) {
    this.bornDate = bornDate;
}

public int getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(int role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public String[] getRoles() {
    return rolesArray;
}

public List<UserMessage> getUserMessagesRecive() {
    return userMessagesRecive;
}

public void setUserMessagesRecive(List<UserMessage> userMessagesRecive) {
    this.userMessagesRecive = userMessagesRecive;
}

public List<UserMessage> getUserMessagesSend() {
    return userMessagesSend;
}

public void setUserMessagesSend(List<UserMessage> userMessagesSend) {
    this.userMessagesSend = userMessagesSend;
}

public String getRoleByName(int role) {
    return rolesArray[role];
}

}
```

**And main method:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("medical.center")
@ComponentScan(basePackages =  "medical.center")
    @EntityScan("medical.center") 
@EnableTransactionManagement

public class MedicalCenterApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MedicalCenterApplication.class, args);
```

**and Receptionist Class:**

```
    @RestController

public class ReceptionistController {

@Autowired
private final ReceptionistRepository receptionistRepository;
private final ReceptionistGenerator receptionistGenerator;
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ReceptionistController.class);



public ReceptionistController(ReceptionistRepository receptionistRepository,
        ReceptionistGenerator receptionistGenerator) {
    this.receptionistRepository = receptionistRepository;
    this.receptionistGenerator = receptionistGenerator;
}


@PostConstruct
public void runAtStart() {
    receptionistRepository.save(receptionistGenerator.generate());
}

@GetMapping("/getRecepcionist")
public Receptionist getReceptionist() {
    logger.info("Get Receptionist");
    return receptionistRepository.getOne(1L);
}
```

}

Please help.

Lukasz

Comment: Don't crypt password, hash them with a good hashing algorithm. You might also want to edit out of the question the property name where you store the master password that crypt them.

Comment: I follow your sugestions and i finally  work it out. Thanks for your help.